# custom component not showing up in community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-community, interface

a custom lightning component I just created is not showing up in my community-community builder custom component list as an option to use. I have had this issue before but forget how to make it available. I have created custom domain and activated.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the component is available for communities by adding implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" to

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder.htm

Answer (score 0):

For LWC components, set `isExposed` to `true` and add `<targets>` to the `-meta.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```